# How can I make the first and last UITableView cells stay on screen when scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have noticed in the iTunesConnect iOS app, the first and last cells of the grouped UITableView stay on screen even though the other cells are scrolling through them. They also move with the tableview. For example when scrolling to the bottom of the table (moving up), the last cell moves up with the table as it leaves the bottom of its position on screen.

Does anyone have an example of how this could be done? I have tried setting the header and footer views but these scroll off screen when moving the tableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use a plain UITableView with Header and Footer set, and "skin"/theme your custom UITableViewCells to look like grouped UITableViewCells.

you'd might want to have a look over [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for some pointers on how to achieve this.